VS Code -- openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory gcc [Ln 4, Col 10]
I am trying to implement a time attack. Briefly there are these steps
a) Timing Measurement ( <time.h> to measure time )
b) Cryptographic Operations (For AES encryption, i am using OpenSSL)
c) Attack Implementation
for the b) section. I am facing this path and no such file issue. I have been solving it by installing openssl etc. properly. I am providing correct paths in c_cpp_properties.json files. But still issue remains somewhat same. It is unable to detect aes.h file.
c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I run this command in cmd gcc test.c -o test -I"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include" -L"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\x64\MD" -l:libssl.lib -l:libcrypto.lib to compile the C code and link against the OpenSSL libraries (libssl and libcrypto).
It gives me these errors:
E:\Iceland\University Stuff\Studies\2nd Semester Courses\Applied Cryptography\Week 10\Project>gcc test.c -o test -I"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include" -L"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\VC\x64\MD" -l:libssl.lib -l:libcrypto.lib
test.c: In function 'time_aes_encryption':
test.c:10:5: warning: 'AES_set_encrypt_key' is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   10 |     AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_key);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.c:4:
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include/openssl/aes.h:51:5: note: declared here
   51 | int AES_set_encrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, const int bits,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:12:5: warning: 'AES_encrypt' is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   12 |     AES_encrypt(plaintext, NULL, &aes_key);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include/openssl/aes.h:57:6: note: declared here
   57 | void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "openssl/aes.h"
#include <string.h>  // Include the string.h header for memset

double time_aes_encryption(const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *plaintext) {
    clock_t start, end;
    AES_KEY aes_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_key);
    start = clock();
    AES_encrypt(plaintext, NULL, &aes_key);
    end = clock();
    return ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

void timing_attack() {
    unsigned char known_key[] = "Sixteen byte key";
    unsigned char plaintext[16] = "plaintext"; // Adjusted to match block size
    double timings[256];
    unsigned char key[16];
    int i;

    printf("Timing attack results:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        memset(key, i, 16);  // Generate a key guess
        timings[i] = time_aes_encryption(key, plaintext);
        printf("Key guess %d: %f seconds\n", i, timings[i]);
    }

    // Analyze timings to infer the key
}

int main() {
    timing_attack();
    return 0;
}

error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
i need assistance with resolving this issue

If test.exe is executing, it has been locked by the operating system.  For obvious reasons, the OS will not allow a program to overwrite itself.  The "No such file or directory" error is unremarkable; it means exactly what it says.  All of the remaining "errors" are just warnings.

E:\Iceland\University Stuff\Studies\2nd Semester Courses\Applied Cryptography\Week 10\Project>test.exe
Timing attack results:
E:\Iceland\University Stuff\Studies\2nd Semester Courses\Applied Cryptography\Week 10\Project>

"test" command gives nothing.
